# Trying to start up IE on watir-webdriver on windows xp, getting "Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - bind(2)", stacktrace points to 'port_prober'

Tags: ruby, internet-explorer-8, webdriver, port, watir-webdriver

So I'm on Windows XP, and I'm trying to get the watir-webdriver to run Internet Explorer 8. I've already added IEDriverServer.exe to the /bin for cygwin. I also disabled the windows firewall and anti-virus software temporarily, and am still getting this error message.

```
w = Watir::Browser.new :ie 
#=>
Errno::EPERM: Operation not permitted - bind(2)
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:28:in `initialize' from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:28:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:28:in `block in free?' rom /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:26:in `each'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:26:in `free?'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/port_prober.rb:5:in `above'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:18:in `block in initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:18:in `delete'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/ie/bridge.rb:18:in `initialize'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:35:in `new'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver/common/driver.rb:35:in `for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/selenium-webdriver-2.31.0/lib/selenium/webdriver.rb:67:in `for'
from /usr/lib/ruby/gems/1.9.1/gems/watir-webdriver-0.6.2/lib/watir-webdriver/browser.rb:46:in `initialize'
from (irb):3:in `new'
```

Note the first time I ran this program, though it crashed immediately with the same error message, I got a dialog box from windows asking me if I wanted to block some action. I told it to "unblock" the action.

Answer (score 1):

It seems your IE profile has some issue, better you remove IE and re-install it and then try to invoke the browser with you code, It should work.
Or try to update the IE that can also repair your browser.